# Gridview Hyperlink column want display xml nodes as a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, hyperlink

I have the following XML file:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <FirstName><a href='profile1.html'>Jon</a></FirstName>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

what am attempting to do is have the FirstName to display as a hyperlink that directs the user to a profile page (web page).

The results from the XML file are displayed via a gridview after the user enters the first name into a text field and clicks the search button. However, the first name (search result) is currently being displayed as plain text.

The following is the code behind the search button:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Sammer\source\repos\MisaImports\MisaImports\data\Employee.xml");
        var query = from r in document.Descendants("Employee")
                    where ((string)r.Element("FirstName").Value).Contains(txtSearch.Text) || ((string)r.Element("FirstName").Value).ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text)
                    select new
                    {

                        FirstName = r.Element("FirstName").Value,
                        //Age = r.Element("Age").Value
                    };

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

...the following depicts how I set up the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                          BorderWidth="1px" 
                          CellPadding="2" 
                          EnableModelValidation="True" 
                          ForeColor="white"
                          GridLines="None" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          EmptyDataText="No records Found">
                          <Columns>
                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Keyword"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                          </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                          </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

My question is, how do I get the first name to diplay as a hyperlink? Thanks in adavnce for any help rendered.

Comment: What is happening with your code? Hyperlink _or_ how to fetch First name? Be specific.

Comment: Rahul Singh - Currently, when the search button is clicked, I get the expected results from the XML file; for example, if I enter Jon or any name that is stored within the XML file, the name is returned via the Gridview hyperlink column. What am trying to do now is get the name to return as a hyperlink that will direct the user to a respective website when the first name is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the `Url` like this:-

```
 select new
         {
            FirstName = r.Element("FirstName").Value,
            Profile = x.Element("FirstName")?.Element("a")?.Attribute("href")?.Value ?? ""
         };
```

Finally bind the `NavigateUrl` property like this:-

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' 
  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("profile") %>' />
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul Singh, the solution worked perfectly.